# Unicode characters in my PHP configuration

Tags: php, php-fpm, ubuntu-12.04, php.ini, unicode

Earlier today I was having an issue where I [couldn't setup my PHP7 remote interpreter on PhpStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40717349/phpstorm-does-not-detect-my-php-7-remote-interpreter?noredirect=1#comment68664402_40717349)

I ended up **finding out that I have unicode characters in my PHP configuration**:

[image]

I have no idea how that happened and I probably would never have noticed without that PHPStorm issue. I searched here and here but only found posts about setting up encoding. **I couldn't find any reference to `phpd` in my ini files so I reckon it's a core thing.**

I'm running PHP 7.0.13 on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS and PHP is installed via ap-get.

Extra info: when I run the following from CLI I don't get the unicode characters:

```
php -r "print_r(ini_get_all());" | grep "phpd"
    [phpd] => Array
    [phpd.t] => Array
```

**Any idea what I could do to fix that ?**

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, this is caused by ionCube loader (running the last 6.0.6 version). After disabling the extension, the phpd values disappear. I've contacted them to report the bug.